# How do I test the number of queries that happen over time in the Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, testing

For some background - I'm writing an abstraction of some Entity Framework functionality to make the work of those using the Data Access Layer a little easier. I'm doing this via proxies / wrappers, and I am at the point where I'd like to test the successful use of EF's `Include()`. (But non of that is relevant for the specific problem here (just want to avoid people suggesting "don't test EF functionality" (I'm delegating the Include method to EF, which is what I'm actually testing)))

Ideally, I'd like to define a block (maybe via `using`) and have that block count the number of queries that happen within that block.

Using some psuedo-code, here is the behavior I would like:

```
var user = new User(id);


using(var queryCounter = new QueryCounter()){
  user.Books.SelectMany(b => b.Pages);


  Assert.Equal(2, queryCounter.NumberOfDetectedQueries);
  // the above assert would fail, due to not using the `Include` keyword.
  // as the two queries should be to select books and page ids and 
  // then to actually select the pages
}
```

Is there a way to achieve something like the above query counting?

---

UPDATE:

Thanks to @Ilya Chumakov for providing insight in to query interceptors. I've been able to get the syntax in the above example via an additional class:

```
public class QueryCounter : IDisposable
{
    public int Count => GlobalCounter.QueryCount;

    public QueryCounter()
    {
        GlobalCounter.QueryCount = 0;
        GlobalCounter.Active = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        GlobalCounter.Active = false;
        GlobalCounter.QueryCount = 0; //
    }
}
```

and then just adding an active field to the GlobalCounter

```
public static class GlobalCounter
{
    public static int QueryCount = 0;
    public static bool Active = false;
}
```

and modifying each of the interceptor methods like so:

```
#if DEBUG
        if (!GlobalCounter.Active) return;
        GlobalCounter.QueryCount++;
        // or whatever output class/method works for you
        Trace.Write("Current Query Count: " + GlobalCounter.QueryCount + " -- ");
        Trace.WriteLine(command.CommandText);
#endif
```

Now, my tests look like this:

```
        using (var counter = new QueryCounter())
        {
            var pages = user.Books.First().Pages;
            Assert.Equal(1, counter.Count);
        }
```

Comment: You're aiming at accessing `queryCounter` after it was (supposedly) disposed. Although I believe the `using` here is purely for the sake of code beauty.

Comment: yeah, maybe the Assert would go in the using after all the calls. I'll update to respect dispose

Comment: You might want to check out Entity Framework Profiler here. https://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/EFProf

Comment: I like the goals behind it. It's not free though :-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may be achieved with interceptor:

```
class EfCommandInterceptor : IDbCommandInterceptor
{
    public void NonQueryExecuted(System.Data.Common.DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
    {
        GlobalCounter.QueryCount++;
    }

    public void ReaderExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
    {
        GlobalCounter.QueryCount++;
    }

    public void ScalarExecuted(System.Data.Common.DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext)
    {
        GlobalCounter.QueryCount++;
    }

    //other methods are empty
}
```

`GlobalCounter` class keeps the global variable:

```
static class GlobalCounter
{
    public static int QueryCount { get; set; }
}
```

Register the interceptor:

```
public class EntityConfigiration : DbConfiguration
{
    public EntityConfigiration()
    {
        this.AddInterceptor(new EfCommandInterceptor());
    }
}
```

The `EntityConfigiration` class will be registered automatically. You may register interceptors in config file instead.

[Entity Framework Tutorial: Interception](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/database-command-interception.aspx)

[Code-Based Configuration (EF6 onwards)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj680699.aspx)

Then use:

```
[Test]
public void CalculateQueryCount()
{
    GlobalCounter.QueryCount = 0;

    using (var context = new YourContext())
    {
        //queries
    }

    int actual = GlobalCounter.QueryCount;
}
```

This `EfCommandInterceptor` code is single-threaded. For a multi-threaded test the locking (`lock`, `Interlocked.Increment` etc.) should be used instead of `++`.

Comment: How does the EntityConfiguration / DbConfiguration get picked up by my context?

Comment: @NullVoxPopuli it registered automatically and should in the same assembly with dbcontext. Interceptor may be registered in config as well. I've provided more details to answer.

Comment: Cool, I'll give this a go. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: I added an additional class in my question that allows the use of the using block :-)